# how to serve images from static folder in expressjs, reactjs, nginx [dublicate]

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, nginx

So problem is, I can't serve images from my web site that deployed to the server.
Project works fine locally. But in the server not.
I know this question asked many times. But I didn't find my answer for related question.
I have a web app that deployed to the AWS ubuntu server. Nginx used for reverse proxy.
Web site works fine except serving images. Uploaded images stored in location /server/public/images directory. When requesting image from url like this: https://domain/static/images/IMG_0001.jpg it's nothing returns.

Project directories:

```
├──var
│  ├──www
│  │   ├──project
│  │   │    ├──server
│  │   │    │  ├──...
│  │   │    │  ├──public/images
│  │   │    │  └──...
│  │   │    └──client
│  │   │       └──build
```

Files are:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const db = require('./models');
const router = require('./router');
const PORT = 4000;
db.CONNECT_DB();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: '*'}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1', () => { 
    db.REFRESH_DB();
    console.log(`Server is running at port ${PORT}`); 
});
```

How I'm getting images in reactjs frontend side:

```
https://domain/static/images
```

nginx config file

```
server {
        root /var/www/project/client/build;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /static/ {
             autoindex on;
             # proxy_pass http://localhost:4000; # with this also tested
             alias /var/www/project/server/public/;
             # root /var/www/project/server/public/; # with this also tested

        }
}
```

I've tested in 3.rd location: `/api, /api/static, /static`

I've restarted nginx with
`sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Any solution for this problem, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using NGINX as a simple reverse-proxy should be enough for your case:

```
server {
        root /var/www/project/client/build;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Comment: with your config (without /api) nginx gives error:
"Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details."

Comment: Whoops. Removed the conflicting block.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. This time not only images but whole website not response. CANNOT GET and 404 Not Found.
My express app requesting routes via prefix /api.